# WITH statement VS subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

What are the benefits of using such syntax:

```
WITH
  cte1 AS (SELECT a, b FROM table1),
  cte2 AS (SELECT c, d FROM table2)
SELECT b, d FROM cte1 JOIN cte2
WHERE cte1.a = cte2.c;
```

instead:

```
SELECT b, d 
FROM (SELECT a, b FROM table1) AS cte1 
JOIN (SELECT c, d FROM table2) AS cte2
WHERE cte1.a = cte2.c;
```

I understand this is new to MySQL 8?

Comment: WITH AS.. can be reused where subquery's can't be reused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL 8 is a considerable re-write on MySQL.  I believe both will perform the same way -- because MySQL has improved the handling of subqueries.

That said, the second version is compatible with earlier versions of MySQL.  The first version is handy for a few reasons:

- It allows re-use of the expressions.  A subquery only appears once in a query.  A CTE can be references multiple times.
- CTEs can refer to other CTEs.  This prevents a nesting problem with lots of subqueries.
- CTEs enable recursive CTEs which are handy.

I wouldn't recommend using either subqueries or CTEs just to select particular columns.  However, I'm guessing that is for illustration purposes only and tangential to your actual question.

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-optimization.html) is the reference that they are the same from an optimization perspective:

> For derived tables (subqueries in the FROM clause), the optimizer has
>   these choices:
>
> - Merge the derived table into the outer query block
> - Materialize the derived table to an internal temporary table
>
> For view references and common table expressions, the optimizer has
>   the same choices as for derived tables.