# computed column to use further in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know how can i use two columns already computed in sql query to get one more result from their values.
my query is

```
SELECT s.date date
     , p.id
     , SUM(COALESCE(p.avgcost,0)) costofsale
     , SUM( COALESCE(s.actual_payable, 0 ) ) total_sales
     , (total_sales - costofsale) tots 
  FROM sales s
  LEFT 
  JOIN sale_items si 
    on si.sale_id = s.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN products p 
    on p.id = si.product_id 
 WHERE DATE(s.date) =  DATE('2019-09-10 14:48:50')
```

I want to get the result from total_sales - costofsale that is already computed in query.

I don't want to alter or update my table.

I just need to use those two columns to give me the result by calculating them.

I have not found any solution over google.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8 includes WITH statements which allows for creating calculated values without using variables.

[WITH statement VS subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744787/with-statement-vs-subquery)